# Is this a valid ssl certificate for facebook fb_ca_chain_bundle

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating a facebook app and i have downloaded the facebook PHP SDK from github.com.When i try to populate facebook canvas with my app, I get a feedback that my server certificate is invalid. I understand that i need an ssl certificate on my server to create to serve my apps on facebook but there's  a **fb_ca_chain_bundle** file that comes with the facebook PHP SDK. Is this the ssl certificate I need.If it is how do i configure and Install it on my server? Thanks in advance for your intelligible replies.

Answer (score 0):

The **fb_ca_chain_bundle** is used by the Facebook PHP SDK to verify its SSL connection to Facebook. It is not the SSL certificate that you need to secure communication to your own server. You will have to purchase and install your own SSL certificate.

Comment: Thanks so much Alex! Do you have any suggestions as to where I can get an ssl certificate that serves this purpose at the cheapest possible price?? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I recently purchased an SSL certificate through [Cheap SSLs](http://www.cheapssls.com/). Lowest prices I've seen: $5 for a standard SSL certificate for a year.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. You have been of immense help. The other thing i am led to believe is that the installation of the certificate is a tedious process. Kindly shed some light on this.

Comment: It's mostly a process of putting the certificate and key files in a reasonable location, and telling your webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc.) where those files are. You should be able to find documentation for the web server that you're using. If you're using Amazon Web Service's Elastic Load Balancer it's even easier -- you just upload your certificate and key to AWS and you're good to go.